# Handle types from optional dependencies in generated .d.ts files

Tags: typescript

I have a library where some files use optional dependencies declared in `peerDependencies`, and the application using the library must include the matching dependencies itself if it wants to use certain components of the library.
This works, but in an application NOT using those parts of the library, I get errors in the `.d.ts` files of the library due to imports of types in the optional dependencies, which now don't exist on the `node_modules` path.

If I use `skipLibCheck` in `tsconfig.json`, the errors are gone, but I'm not entirely sure what other consequences there are by skipping lib check.
Is there some other way, either to have my library strip exposing types from optional 3rd party libraries, or with some compiler option in my application which doesn't completely skip lib check, but ignores import errors in .d.ts files, for example by treating missing types as `any`?

Example setup:

---

`my-optional-dependency` module:

index.ts:

```
export class Foo {
  constructor(readonly value: string) {
  }
}
```

---

`my-library` module:

package.json:

```
  devDependencies: {
    "my-optional-dependency": "^1.0.0"
  },
  peerDependencies: {
    "my-optional-dependency": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

index.ts:

```
import {Foo} from 'optional-dependency';

export function hello() {
  console.log('Hello, world!');
}
export async function wtf(value: string): Foo {
  const {Foo} = await import('my-optional-dependency');

  return new Foo(value);
}
```

---

`my-app` module:

package.json:

```
  dependencies: {
    "my-library": "^1.0.0",
    "my-optional-dependency": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

index.ts:

```
import {wtf} from 'my-library';

async function foo() {
  const foo = await wtf('This works');
}
```

---

`my-other-app` module:

package.json:

```
  dependencies: {
    "my-library": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

index.ts:

```
import {hello} from 'my-library';

hello();
```

Both apps work, and if using tools such as `webpack`, the code can be packaged without errors. The optional dependency is dynamically imported only inside the `wtf` function, so `my-other-app` will not get any error when `my-optional-dependency` is not in `node_modules`.

BUT, compiling using plain `tsc` without `skipLibCheck` will produce:

```
node_modules/my-library/dist/index.d.ts:1:19 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'my-optional-dependencies' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import {Foo} from 'optional-dependency';
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I read somewhere regarding optional dependencies that the compiler would treat a missing type as `any`, which would suit me fine here. But how would I do that without resorting to `skipLibCheck`?
If I remove the type dependency to `Foo` completely from `wtf`, I no longer get a type-safe `wtf` function.
Also, I don't want to put optional parts of the library in a sub-path so that it's imported using `my-library/dist/optional` or similar.

Is there a good solution here?